# Security: Rails + Nginx HTTPS, should I proxy_pass with https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I successfully moved my Rails app to https with the following Nginx config:

```
upstream example_staging {
  server                localhost:3000;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name           example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://example_staging;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
  }
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/privkey.pem;
  # other configs ...
}
```

The good thing is that I did not have to change anything in Rails, since it is still receiving http queries.

But I'm wondering if there might be a security breach because of that... Like the cookie/session encryption might be endangered?

Should I do something like:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass          https://example_staging; # with HTTPS
  proxy_read_timeout  90;
}
```

and let Rails know about certificates or am I fine like that? (which would be great because it is simple, and it must be faster since there's no need for two decryptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is completely under your control and your upstream traffic never leaves the server (I'd also advise to switch to unix sockets for additional security and some performance) there's no need to encrypt.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'll have a look